# Partial String Matching between Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen discussions on partial string match merges [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983398/pandas-join-on-partial-string-match-like-excel-vlookup), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52265419/join-dataframes-based-on-partial-string-match-between-columns), and elsewhere, but nothing on how to do it on the table containing the superstring instead of the substring.

Given sample data like

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'uri': ['http://www.foo.com/index', 
                            'https://bar.net/directory', 
                            'www.baz.gov/aboutus']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'fqdn': ['www.foo.com',
                             'www.qux.mil']})
```

```py
print(df1)

                         uri
0   http://www.foo.com/index
1  https://bar.net/directory
2        www.baz.gov/aboutus
```

```py
print(df2)

          fqdn
0  www.foo.com
1  www.qux.mil
```

my end goal is to remove the rows from `df1` that contain *any* substring in `df2`. In the actual data, `df1` has several million rows and `df2` has a few hundred, and any given row in `df1` will have at most one substring in `df2`.

Given the sample data, I hope to end up with a dataframe like

```py
                         uri
0  https://bar.net/directory
1        www.baz.gov/aboutus
```

and by my logic, the intermediate step is to generate

```py
                         uri           fqdn
0   http://www.foo.com/index    www.foo.com
1  https://bar.net/directory         np.NaN
2        www.baz.gov/aboutus         np.NaN
```

but I can't figure out how to check all of `df2`'s values inside of `df1.apply()`.

---

Edit:

While both answers below work, I got the fastest results in my specific scenario by compiling a regex object and using `extract`:

```py
import re

fqdn_list= re.compile(f"({'|'.join(df2.fqdn)})")

df1['fqdn'] = df1.uri.str.extract(fqdn_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the strings from `df2` with the pipe (`|`) as seperator which is the `or` operator in regex. This way we can check if the `df1` contains any of these strings and remove them with `str.contains` and `~` which is the `not` operator;

```
m = ~df1['uri'].str.contains('|'.join(df2['fqdn']))
df1[m]
```

**Output**

```
                         uri
1  https://bar.net/directory
2        www.baz.gov/aboutus
```

Comment: While this accomplishes what I need without the middle step when tested on the toy set, when applied to even a subset of the real data it never finishes, whereas WeNYoBen's approach runs almost instantly. Is that weird?

Comment: Yes, it was weird, and it was because of a typo.

Comment: Upon further testing using samples of up to 1M strings, your solution is approximately 20% faster.

Comment: That's nice to hear. Glad I could help. @Andy

Comment: I managed to get a significant speed boost (~25%) by compiling a regex object, check the bottom of my question if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need ? `str.findall`

```
df1.uri.str.findall(df2.fqdn.str.cat(sep='|')).str[0]
Out[192]: 
0    www.foo.com
1            NaN
2            NaN
Name: uri, dtype: object
#df1['fqdn']=df1.uri.str.findall(df2.fqdn.str.cat(sep='|')).str[0]
```

Comment: +1 This works perfectly on the toy example, but I don't know if it scales to the size of my set or if I need something with short-circuiting. I'm getting ahead of myself. I'll accept once I can test in the morning.