# Pandas: left join/right join on partial string match

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to perform  left join/right join on partial string match in python. There have been many questions related to this on StackOverflow but I cannot apply them in my case. Hope that someone can guide me in the right direction. I have the following two pandas dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'BName': ['10123', '10345', 'apple2', 'apple3', 'orange'],
                    'Description': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd','ee']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'RefName': ['10345haha', 'bb10123', 'apple2hre', 'orangenono',"bye"],
                    'Type': ['01', '03', '04', '02','05'],
                    'Amount': ['250', '275', '260', '280','107'],
                    'Comment': ['bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla','bla']})

print(df1)
    BName Description
0   10123          aa
1   10345          bb
2  apple2          cc
3  apple3          dd
4  orange          ee

print(df2)
     RefName Type Amount Comment
0   10345haha   01    250     bla
1     bb10123   03    275     bla
2   apple2hre   04    260     bla
3  orangenono   02    280     bla
4         bye   05    107     bla
```

I want to retain the main information in df2 while adding the information from df1. However, the left join/right join function does not work in my case because the names are not exactly the same.

My desired output is like this:

```
      RefName  Type Amount Comment   Description
0   10345haha   01    250     bla  bb
1     bb10123   03    275     bla  aa
2   apple2hre   04    260     bla  cc
3  orangenono   02    280     bla  ee
4         bye   05    107     bla  None
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983398/pandas-join-on-partial-string-match-like-excel-vlookup](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
Inspired by the above post, I tried to do something like this:

```
df4 = df2.copy()
df4['BName'] = [val for idx, val in enumerate(df1['BName']) if val in df2['RefName'][idx]]
df_m4 = df1.merge(df4, how='right', on='BName')
```

But then this error arises,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    384                 try:
--> 385                     return self._range.index(new_key)
    386                 except ValueError as err:

ValueError: 12957 is not in range
```

I am not sure if there is any other possible ways to solve the problem (not necessarily by solving the error above).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is going to be painfully slow, especially one threaded.

Answer (score 2):

Create a regex pattern using the values from `BName` column, then use `str.extract` to extract the occurrence of this regex pattern from the values in `RefName` column to create a new column `BName` in `df2` then left merge `df2` with `df1` to get the result

```
rpat = r'(%s)' % '|'.join(df1['BName'])
df2['BName'] = df2['RefName'].str.extract(rpat)

df2.merge(df1, how='left')
```

---

```
      RefName Type Amount Comment   BName Description
0   10345haha   01    250     bla   10345          bb
1     bb10123   03    275     bla   10123          aa
2   apple2hre   04    260     bla  apple2          cc
3  orangenono   02    280     bla  orange          ee
4         bye   05    107     bla     NaN         NaN
```