# How to extract the value from other dataframe based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have attached two dataframes and a sample of their data in the screenshot below.

In dataframe B, for `each equipment ID`, we will look into dataframe A using the columns `'CONSTRUCTION_TYPE', 'CONSTRUCTOR', and 'CONSTRUCTION_TYPE_FAMILY'`.

If the conditions match, it will extract two values:
the number of steps for refurbishment and the number of steps for preventive maintenance. However, I am facing a challenge in writing the conditions because the `'CONSTRUCTION_TYPE_FAMILY'` column has multiple conditions.

Dataframe A
[image]

Dataframe B
[image]

**Sample data for construction type family  column**

"""RFR 4"" OR ""RR 2"""

""" RFR 6"" OR ""RR 10"""

"RFR 4"

'"M" OR "T" OR "V"

"F" OR "H3xx" OR "300 A" OR "RCM " OR "RBF" OR "UCB"

NOT: RFR 4, RR 2, RFR 6, RR 10, R, C, D, M,T, V, VRC,VM, V, F, H3xx, 300 A, RCM, RBF, UCB, A vide

**Sample data for Construction type column**

Not "TFO-Reg (tri) RFR 4 New upgrade 2016 {???A}"

Not "TFO-Reg (tri) RFR 6 New upgrade 2016 {800A} "

TFO-Reg (tri) RFR 4 New upgrade 2016 {???A}

TFO-Reg (tri) RFR 6 New upgrade 2016 {800A}

Comment: What do you mean by "'CONSTRUCTION_TYPE_FAMILY' column has multiple conditions."?

Comment: @AmriRasyidi he/she means the contstructor_type_family has "RFR4 or RR2" in df A. but in df B he has one value RFR 4. So instead of equality join it will be partial join based on text match.

or you can pivot down table A and join with table B under equality conditions

Comment: Also Can you paste the first few rows of data in the question itself  ?

Comment: In that case, maybe this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983398/pandas-join-on-partial-string-match-like-excel-vlookup) can help

Comment: @Equinox I added the first few rows of data construction type family & Construction type